# How do you define a global label in ARM assembly via C?

Tags: assembly, arm

I wish to create a global label in the compiled binary for the ARM ISA but I wish to insert a global label to the end of the declaration of the global variables (for example "endofdata" label). The reason for that is that I can create an entry to the ELF's symbol table and later on to process the binary with a script and to acquire the specific .data segment so that I know where it ends (its offset).

I try to use the asm(""); command but I get bad instruction messages or junk by the compiler. 
Could someone provide me the proper syntax of the asm() command for global label insertion in ARM assembly?

by using:

> asm("endofcode:");

I created an entry but its LOCAL.

Comment: You can't do this in assembly.  Instead, you need to ask the linker to add such a symbol during linking.  Normally, the linker creates a symbol `edata` pointing to the end of the data segment, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: What is the compiler you are using?

Comment: what makes you think this will end up at the end of data?  your best bet is something in the linker script which if you didnt write the linker script and are using a canned one probably already has a label at the end of data.

Comment: .globl endofcode ; endofcode:

Comment: in gnu assembler, but remember assembly language is not target specific but assembler/tool specific so the exact syntax will vary from assembler to assembler (gnu, arm, kiel, others)

Comment: @old_timer After cross-compiling and using readelf tool to read the .symtab I can verify that indeed this label is shown as GLOBAL in the binary.